# No consigo habilitar el estado disabled en un form:checkbox

Tags: jquery, spring-webflow

Estoy trabajando con Spring webflow y tengo un elemento form:checkbox de tipo switch en mi jsp que por defecto debe estar disabled.
Me estoy volviendo loco intentando habilitarlo mediante JQuery cuando se cumple una condición.

```
<form:checkbox id="anId" path="" value="" cssClass="js-switch" disabled="true"/>
```

El código html que genera es así:

```
<input id="anId" class="js-switch" disabled="" type="checkbox" value="" data-switchery="true" style="display: none;">
<span class="switchery" id="anId" style="">
<small style=""></small>
</span>
```

He probado cambiando el disabled a true, eliminando el atributo disabled, también:

```
$("#anId").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

¿Cómo debería implementar esto para que funcione?

Marco tu respuesta correcta porque con la información que di, lo es. El problema radica en:

```
<span style="patatan:a_lot_of_stuff;"  class="switchery" id="anId"  />
```

que no copié por brevedad, es quien le da la apariencia de disabled al mismo. Sabiendo eso, solo es:

```
$("span#anId").attr("style", "pataton:otra_castaña;");
```

y

```
<small style="etc" />
```

pues más de lo mismo:

```
$("span#anId small").attr("style", "stuff");
```

Con esto no funciona el evento click ni a la fuerza, intenté:

```
$("span#anId").off("click");
```

...al principio (ni sé porqué) pero luego lo usé cuando quiero que vuelva a estar disabled y se comporte como tal. Lo que hice:

```
$("div#el_que_lo_contiene").click(function(){
    if($("span#anId small").css("left")=="20px"){
        $("span#anId small").attr("style", "left:0px;y:mas;"); 
        $("input#anId").val(false);
    } else {
        $("span#anId small").attr("style", "left:20px;y:mas;"); 
        $("input#anId").val(true);
    }
});
```

Para enviar el valor que contiene el input (que es quien realmente lo almacena) hago algo asi:

```
$("send").click(function(){
    $("input#anId").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

y debería llegar al controller... Luego controlar el comportamiento y listo.

Comment: Cuando dices que has probado cambiando el disabled a true,  has probado esto: `$("input.anId").attr("disabled", true);`?

Comment: Sí también lo he probado y no surte ningún efecto, y cuando hago      removeAttr("disabled") desaparece el disabled pero sin embargo el control sigue disabled... y me he equivocado quería decir que lo pongo a false, perdón.

Comment: Mira a ver si funciona con $("input.anId").removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, lo he probado y me elimina el disabled en el código html pero sigue  estando disabled... También he probado a cargarme con .remove todo lo que genera y hacer un append (aunque es un poco chapucero creo yo), el problema es que cuando hago el append me lo añade también disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando hagas clic en un botón que quieras que deshabilite o active un checkbox, deberás usar el siguiente código:

https://jsfiddle.net/tcbr22b6/

```
$("button").on("click", function() {
    if($("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled")) {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", false)
    }
    else {
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", true)
    }
});
```

Aquí lo que hace es comprobar si la propiedad `disabled` está activa o no, y en función de ello deshabilita o no el checkbox.
Aquí ya deberás tú poner id's, clases, o como lo quieras realizar.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, he probado el código que planteas y efectivamente elimina el disabled del input, el problema es que el código que genera mi jsp crea un input:checkbox con style=display:none; y debajo el control que realmente muestra y que está disabled:    <span class="switchery" id="anId" style="">
<small style=""></small>
</span> No tiene la propiedad disabled por ningún lado... y sin embargo ese span está disabled... no sé si me explico